# how to execute the date command in a python program

Tags: python, date

The following is the code:

```
import os
#f=os.popen('date -d @1358193598 +%m/%d/%y')
f=os.popen('date')
print(f)
```

I tied both ways, and it gave me an error of "broken pipe". Do you happen to know how to deal with this situation? I also tried to use the subprocess module, and it does not work either. The error message is as the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t_2.py", line 23, in <module>
    dates.append(transfer_date_format(raw_date))
  File "t_2.py", line 6, in transfer_date_format
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Because you need full path or ``os.system`` (it uses ``PATH`` env). But why do you need it? There is an API in Python for dates

Comment: use `datetime` module

Comment: good point. maybe I can simply use python module to implement this instead of running unix commands. I will dig into it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-bash-backticks-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `os.system`

```
f=os.system('date')
```

Here it will save `exit` code to the variable `f`

If you want to take output of executed command to the variable, try

```
f=os.popen('date').read()
print f
```

Comment: "f=os.system" will only run the command, right? what if I'd like to get the output of the command to a string instead?

Comment: You can take output of executed command using 
`f=os.popen('date').read()`